# Can someone please point me to the "community guidelines"?

Tags: support

I'm just curious if anyone has a copy of the rules.  Something in writing.  @Tinkeringbell called them "community guidelines."

Answer (score 10):

In general, information about the site, how it works, and how to use it can be found in the [help center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help). There are a number of different pages there that are helpful for newer users. Some are generic and apply to all Stack Exchange sites; others are slightly different and modified for different sites (for instance, we've edited [this page about asking questions](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Tinkeringbell, in their edit summary for [revision 8 of one of your questions](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/revisions/7712/8), was pointing you to [this meta post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/224/102). Stack Exchange lets you write answers to your own questions if you've figured them out; this helps future users who see the question, because your solution is now available to them. What we've decided on IPS - and what is a policy on various other Stack Exchange sites -is that if you come up with a solution that you've used, you should write it as an answer to your question, rather than add it in along with the rest of the question text. This lets people vote on it.

I'll also note that Tinkeringbell's request to "Be Nice" is a reference to our [Be Nice](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy, which is standard across Stack Exchange. [Your previous revision](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/revisions/7712/7) contained the line

> UPDATE This post was closed at the whim of the users listed below, but given it's popularity, I wanted to give an update.

which was partially a jab at the folks who closed the question - and not on a whim. That violates the Be Nice policy, which is another reason to remove that particular sentence (in addition to the fact that the question shouldn't contain a solution that you eventually came up with).

Comment: You read an awful lot into a simple question.  LOL

Comment: Can you please tell me who "we" are?  I noticed that random users like to use the word "we" on this site, which infers some sort of gang or affiliation.  When you say "we've edited this page about asking questions", who are "we."  Are you representatives of Stack Exchange? Do you have a phone number or title?

Comment: Also, I'm not able to answer that question, so that's why I updated the question.  You'll find this funny... people actually read my question.  Isn't that something.  Do you know they just answered it as thought I was asking to them in person.  haha.  I'm still laughing at them.  Geez, if they had just gone to the "help center" (that's an exceptional resource by the way) they would know that *the question is more important than the answer* on this site.

Comment: @rbsdca The word "we" is used a lot because the members of this site are the ones who develop the policy of the site. For instance the boundaries of what is and isn't on topic were developed organically as the site grew. Not all policies are site specific. Some rules like **be nice** are set in stone but many edge cases like *should the OP's solution be added to the question?* are left to particular exchanges to decide. If you want to be involved with the site you are encouraged to come join the discussion on meta.

Comment: In short *we* use *we* when talking about site policy because *we* are the ones who get work together to set it.

Comment: as @sphennings says - Moderation is a community decision, not solely up to the elected/chosen caretakers (err, moderators). Site scope and other relevant information is determined on meta, again by the community. So, since it is a communal effort, people generally use the inclusive "we" when discussing the topic. It takes a village and so forth.

Comment: Also - What HDE outlines in the answer above, is pretty much reflective of every SE community. Every community will have its own vagaries, but the base information reflected in this answer holds true across all SE sites.